# Send string to a fully functional REPL in Emacs on Windows?

Tags: microsoft-windows, ansi-term, comint, repl

**Summary.** Is there a way to get fully functional REPLs on Windows running in Emacs. I want to avoid the maintenance burden associated with `comint`.

---

**Long version.** In many cases I dislike how the built-in REPL-interaction of programming modes works. For instance, I may prefer to use iPython directly, rather than relying on an interaction layer handling things like completion when I press `TAB`.

However, I also need the ability to send code directly to the REPL.

If I were using Emacs exclusively on Linux, I'd simply use `M-x ansi-term ipython3` and write my own commands for sending buffer contents. However, on Windows `M-x ansi-term` isn't functional; It has a hardcoded call to `/bin/sh`, but even replacing this with a native `sh.exe` (e.g. from MSYS) only results in an unresponsive buffer.

`comint-mode` isn't viable, because it requires either committing to a lot of work to get interactive features right, or hoping that someone has written it already, actively supports latest features of the language at hand, and hasn't omitted features I need. Mileage here varies a lot depending on the language, and I often see subtle Windows-specific breakage.

As a consequence I am looking for alternatives. Things like

- getting `ansi-term` into working state on Windows,
- sending strings to an external terminal application like `mintty`,
- a language-agnostic repl-layer, that leaves more of the work to the repl binary than `comint` would.

Is there such a thing?

Comment: Use eshell. It's a shell-like interpreter written in Elisp, so it will work on Windows.

Comment: @aadcg Eshell doesn't allow using the native tab-completion of, say, `IPython` or `julia`.

Comment: That's true. This is off-topic, but IMO the best experience of GNU/Linux on a (relatively powerful) Window machine is to use virtualization (qemu, virtualbox).

Comment: @aadcg If it is about using Linux on a Windows system, I can achieve a lot with WSL2. However, I would like to use Windows-native REPLs in Windows-native Emacs.